# How do I include html file inside another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, shiny

I know that there are a lot of answers to this question, but I have trying them all and I could not resolve this problem.
My specific problem is that I have two files, `index.html` and `part1.html`, and I need include `part1.html` into `index.html`.

I have tried using:

```
.load() function of jquery.
<!--#include file="part1.shtml" -->
include with html like <!--#include file="part1.html" -->
```

but this has resolved my problem,  so why so I need it? I have a page with a lot of code and in this moment is almost impossible to work. Why don't use a server language? I do, but I work with a framework in R called shiny and believe me server language is not a solution xD.

When I use `.load()` I get an error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/... Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Thanks for all.

Comment: `.load()` should work fine..mind posting some code of what you've tried?

Comment: jquery load function should work ? Could you add code how you are loading the html using jquery load function ?

Comment: You need a server rather than just loading it using file:///. MAMP, WAMP or LAMP (for Mac, Windows or Linux respectively) are good things to google.

Answer (score 2):

```
use jquery

    <html> 
      <head> 
        <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
        <script> 
        $(function{
          $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
        });
        </script> 
      </head> 

      <body> 
         <div id="includedContent"></div>
      </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.load` should be working fine. A quick example of this, say you have the following div:

```
<div id="contentDiv"></div>
```

Using jQuery, you can load your separate HTML file into that div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contentDiv").load("part1.html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's something to do with SOP(same origin policy) recently I had the same issue...so I used this...hope you can do it like this...here's the link : http://jsfiddle.net/JKZ2h/1/
my html code:

```
<li><a href="#" class="about-link">About&nbsp;Us</a></li>
<div class="bdy"></div>
```

my js code:

```
$('.about-link').click(function() {
$('.bdy').html('<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"  style="width:100%;height:435px;" src="http://www.erail.in/?R=12622"><iframe>');
})
```

or even this works for a static webpage :
this inside any function...works..:

```
$('.bdy').html('<object style="width:100%;height:435px;"data="http://www.jhsoftech.com/contactus.php">');
```